# How to compare the json value with dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have JSON like this.

```
{
  "currentdatetime": "11",
  "syncinterval_seconds": 4,
  "public_keys": [
    {
      "system": "aa",
      "pubkey": "aa"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "user",
      "user_id": "user",
      "realname": "user_10",
      "emailaddress": "test@gmail.com",
      "accountenabled": false,
      "mustchangepassword": false,
      "passwordhash": "$E6gi",
      "accesslevel": [
         "WORKER"
      ],
      "expiration": "2022-11-02T16:21:52",
      "site_specific": false,
      "symkey": "aaaa",
      "privatekey": "aaa"
    },
  ]
}
```

and I created a dictionary like this which maps usernames to their respective access level

```
user_access = {
  "user": "WORKER",
  "user2": "ADMIN",
  "user3": "WORKER",
  "user4": "GENERAL"
}
```

I am trying to verify in my API response json that the defined user has the correct access level.

I wrote a function like this

```
 def LoadUserList(apijson)
     for user_result in apijson[USERS]:
         username = user_result[USER_NAME]
         accesslevel = user_result[accesslevel]
         if (user_result[USER_NAME] == 'user' AND user_result[accesslevel] == 'WORKER')
             print "success"
         else
             print "not matching"
```

But the above code is not working as expected. I don't know how to compare the values in the JSON with the values in the dictionary. How do I fix my code so that it prints "success" for each user in the JSON that has a matching accesslevel value in the `user_access` dictionary?

Comment: Explain "not working as expected", what happens, what should happen?

Comment: this is manual way of checking user and access level. But I already have defined json. struck with how to compare with that api response json

Comment: So, you're trying to check that the API response matches your result?  First, you need `user_result['accesslevel']`, in quotes.  Next, that returns a LIST.  So, you probably want `if user_access[username] in accesslevel:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `apijson` is a `dict`, e.g., generated by applying `json.loads()` on API result:

```py
def LoadUserList(apijson)
    for user in apijson['users']:
        username, accesslevel = user['username'], user['accesslevel']
        if user_access.get(username) in accesslevel:
            print(username, "success")
        else
            print(username, "not matching")
```

Comment: There is one issue with your solution. if the defined value is matching like this user": "WORKER". it is going to success condition.  this is fine. but other values it is going to else part and both block is getting executed. In my case the user_access defined values check anything exist or not in APIjson values. if its there it is correct. else it should come out.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries in python have 2 ways of accessing values by some key.

1. via hard bracket indexers - `apijson["users"]`
2. via `.get` - `apijson.get("users")`

> Note that both are case-sensitive and both are using quotes to pass the values as strings rather than variable names. `USERS = "users"; apijson[USERS]` would be fine as well but `USERS` would need to first be defined.

Additionally -

1. We love colons in python so `def LoadUserList(apijson):` and `if <>:`/`else:`
2. The keywords `or`/`and` are case-sensitive so your example `AND` -> `and`
3. Your example json structure has users[0].accesslevel as an array so your (corrected) `user_result["accesslevel"] == 'WORKER'` won't evaluate to True since `user_result["accesslevel"] = ["WORKER"]`

So with some corrections,

```py
def LoadUserList(apijson):
    for user_result in apijson["users"]:
        username = user_result["username"]
        accesslevel = user_result["accesslevel"]
        user_accesslevel = user_access.get(username)  # "WORKER"
        if (username == 'user' and user_accesslevel in accesslevel):
            print("success")
        else:
            print("not matching")
```